# MySQL comparing CHAR(m) character by character

Tags: c++, mysql, string, comparison, character

In my table one of my fields has a type CHAR(26). Instead of using STRCMP() to compare each character and stop when there isn't match, I want to compare all characters. In a C++ function with std::string or any kind of vector really, it would look like the following:

```
bool lesser(str1, str2)   //str1 < str2
{ 
for (int i = 0; i < str1.length(); i++)
    if (str2[i] < str1[i]) return false;
return true;
}
```

Is it possible to do this in MySQL? I've heard of UDF, but I'm not exactly sure on how this is done. There are many, many, many rows so time is an issue.

Comment: It isn't exactly clear what you are looking for. The function you list is almost identical to the SQL `SELECT strcmp(str1, str2) < 0;`. Your version will exceed the length of str2 if it is shorter than str1 and return true if the strings are equal. Your version will also check all characters in the string in some cases where strcmp() wouldn't. For example: str1="aaaa...(x1000)...aaa", str2="zzzz...(x1000)...zzz".

Comment: First I apologise for the clarity, or lack of. Basically I want an integer comparison except for strings. The strings will always be 26 characters long. I require it to compare all characters in the string. As far as I understand MySQL (which isn't that much to be honest) but 26 digit integers are far too large. The strings aren't numbers, but they represent tuples. I need to compare each coordinate. I believe, but I'm not entirely sure, if you could subtract strings where each new character (s1 - s2)[i] equals s1[i] - s2[i], an equivalent solution would be strcmp(s1 - s2, s1) = -1.

Comment: Actually, it is the subtraction would be the same as numbers with carries, not direct subtraction. If i've confused you further, I'm sorry, but the c++ describes exactly the comparison I need.

Comment: MySQL has a data type called DECIMAL that can store up to 65 digits. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/numeric-types.html

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately it turns the subtraction and then string comparison is not equivalent (which I should have realised, I didn't think about a certain very common test case). I've tried to come up with many different ways to detect this, but none have worked so far. Basically what I need now is a way to detect that a subtraction doesn't involve carries in any digit, that each digit in one number is less than or equal to the other. Hmm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a mysql function to do the same thing that your C++ code does, but you should be able to do it with your own function.  I've not tested this code, but it will probably look something like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION mylesser(s1 CHAR(26), s2 CHAR(26))
   RETURNS BOOL
BEGIN
  DECLARE ndx INT DEFAULT 0;

  WHILE ndx < LENGTH(s1) DO
    IF ORD(MID(s2, ndx, 1)) < ORD(MID(s1, ndx, 1)) THEN 
        RETURN 0;
    END IF
    SET ndx = ndx + 1;
  END WHILE;
  RETURN 1
END;
```

ORD(MID(string, index, 1)) is the only way I was able to find to get the value of a character in a string at a specific position.

I would try this out and see if it's fast enough for you.  If not, you could write a C function to do the same thing, and give it as a UDF to mysql.  I don't have any experience w/ that, but here's the documentation for it: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/adding-functions.html

Comment: Thanks. I haven't yet tested this but you've shown me how to accomplish it using MySQL even if it doesn't work.